# Fixing labels of a 6 x 6 graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Hi I'm very new to Python, and I'm trying to fix the labels because they overlap, (as seen in the picture). I figured the hspace and the wspace is the columns, but I'm not sure exactly how to adjust everything else in the labels, I don't want to mess with the x axis. Is there a way to make this plot look clearer?

Here's what I have:

```
_, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=6, ncols=6, sharex=True)
plt.suptitle('mean activity duration by time of day')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.5)
 
for ax, (activity, df) in zip(axes.ravel(), df_all.groupby('e')):
    (df.groupby('f')
                  .d
                  .mean()
                  .plot(ax=ax,
                        kind='bar',
                        title=activity,
                        xlabel='time'))
```

6 x 6 bar graph:

[image: 6 x 6 bar graph]

Comment: Aside from the answer in the duplicate, you would probably be better off using `seaborn.catplot` with `kind='bar'` and using the `col`  and `col_wrap` parameter. It would mostly replace your entire code with 1 line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use constrained_layout.
- use a larger figure size so your titles are not larger than your axes
- use a smaller font size for the titles.

You can use tight_layout if you prefer, but constrained_layout is more flexible.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your comment :) 
How would I go about using larger figure sizes? Should/can I separate the graphs? (instead making 36 individual plots instead of 36 in one figure)

Comment: The subplots command takes a figsize argument in inches.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `plt.tight_layout`,  adjusts subplot params so that the subplot(s) fits in to the figure area